# Is there a way to check if a value exists in an array in twig?

Tags: templating, array

Done some searching on this but can't quite find what I'm looking for. Most threads are regarding keys.

I want to know if there is a way to test if a value exists in a twig array.

It should be able to check whether the value is a variable, object or an array.

So for example:

```
{% if value not in array %}
    .... do someting
{% endif %}
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 9):

Like you said, to test if a value exists in a Twig array you'd do:

```
{% if myValue in ['apples', 'oranges'] %}
    {# do something... #}
{% endif %}
```

To check whether the value is an array or object you could use the [iterable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/iterable.html) test:

```
{% if myValue is iterable %}
    {# myValue is an array or object #}
{% else %}
    {# myValue is probably a string #}
{% endif %}
```

To be certain, you might be best coming out of Twig using a plugin [Template Variable](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/variables) and doing it directly in PHP.

Comment: Thanks @Jamie I think I will need to create a plugin as it's not working on what I require it for. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Craft 3.7.15 onwards you can use `is array` twig test. More info https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Docs for this now here: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/tests.html#array

```
{{ ['oh', 'hello', 'there'] is array ? 'true' : 'false' }}
{# result: true #}
```

(Relevant changelog now here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/3.8/CHANGELOG.md)